# Looking for an iOS AR Framework or API that suits a specific need

Tags: ios, augmented-reality

I know this subject has been here before I went through most of the questions asking for this but I have already checked numerous options and I still can't find what I'm looking for.
What I need is to develop an app that uses AR to showcase images and videos mostly.

The closest I've come is with [this from Qualcomm](https://developer.qualcomm.com/develop/mobile-technologies/augmented-reality) but when I try to run the code I get a bunch of errors without touching anything. Other than that I've seen the project [here](https://github.com/zac/iphonearkit/) which also looked promising and then the code [from here](https://github.com/omeryavuz/VRToolKit) which is VR instead of AR.

This last code I am able to use perfectly but I do not know if I can add videos which is what I'm looking for. I went through the comments and some of the documentation already but I can't find where to generate my own markers and if I can even do that I don't know if I can add videos.

Any ideas as to a better framework that covers these requirements or has anybody has any experience with any of these 3 (particularly the last one) and can help me out a bit?

Answer (score 2):

You can use junaio. It supports ios and very easy to use

Answer (score 0):

you can download the mobile SDK from metaio for free ( http://www.metaio.com/software/mobile-sdk/ ) - it allows you to load videos as textures. The example that is shipped also demonstrates this functionality.

Another option would be junaio - there is a whole section on videos/media: http://www.junaio.com/develop/docs/documenation/general/media/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you download the latest SDK of Vuforia, the demo codes worked like a charm!

https://ar.qualcomm.at/qdevnet/sdk/ios